# how to get parameter for an ajax request in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web-services

Edit: I solved my prblem, eveyone. I have linked to a wrong javascript page. thats silly. thank u very much though

I have an ajax request GET with parameter random: yes, but when I use PHP to check for the parameter, the parameter doesn't seem to exits

my code is like this:
for ajax

```
function fetchData() {
    new Ajax.Request("webservice.php", {
        method: "get",
        parameters: {random: "yes"},
        onSuccess: displayData,
        onFailure: ajaxFailure,
        onException: ajaxFailure
    });
}
```

and I write PHP to check the parameter

```
if ($_GET["random"] == "yes"){ 
    do something
}else if(isset($_REQUEST["poll"]) && $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"){ 
    //this is b/c i have another ajax request with parameters {poll: "favChar"},
    do something
}
```

I get the error of making ajax request. I have check my PHP code. I enter wwww.domainname.com/webservice.php?random=yes and the page output the results correctly.
Can someone help me? Thank u

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is adding the parameter in the URL:

```
new Ajax.Request("webservice.php?random=yes", {
  // options
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an AJAX obj first: `var http = new XMLHttpRequest();`

***The GET method:***

```
var url = "webservice.php";
var params = "random=yes&param=value";
http.open("GET", url+"?"+params, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [`parameters` requires a Hash-compatible object](http://prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options), so you might have to convert your plain JavaScript hash, like so:

```
function fetchData() {
    new Ajax.Request("webservice.php", {
        method: "get",
        parameters: $H({random: "yes"}),
        onSuccess: displayData,
        onFailure: ajaxFailure,
        onException: ajaxFailure
    });
}
```